# jquery on method not working with window or document

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty simple code:

html:

```
<div id="wrap" style="background-color:gray; height:2000px;">

</div>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){



    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
         console.log(" mouse up \n");


        })  

    }); 
    </script>
```

I replaced `$(document)`  with `$(window)` but with no effect.

Browser: FF 13.0

How to make it work ?

**EDIT:**

**OMG**, I used scroll instead of clicking the mouse to get the 'mouseup' event. What a silly mistake !!!

Comment: did you include jquery ?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/USgbR/

Comment: actually on detecting mouseup, a div is intended to bounce.

Comment: @helmus, jquery included

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sfDAk/1 works fine

Comment: @FelixKling, does not work for me. Could it be any virus or malware for the code to dysfunction in my browser

Comment: @eicto, does not work for me. Could it be any virus or malware for the code to dysfunction in my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/GXrPp/2/

Does you JQuery reference loads correctly ?

**Edit:** Here is my result (in FF14)
[image: Result]

Comment: i think it does, otherwise there would be error message in console

Comment: you used no html to get any scroll

Comment: I added html, still no result.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the event on `document.body`.
`document` and `window` are not DOM elements and do not receive normal events.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of this answer, however jQuery is hand-holding enough to allow the binding of mouse events to `document` - what the OP posted should (and seems to) work.

Comment: what kind of elements are document and window then? what type of events do those receive?